# ASP.Net MVC support for Editor.For(model)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, crud

What is "[ASP.Net MVC support for Editor.For(model)](http://ayende.com/Blog/archive/2010/09/03/the-law-of-conservation-of-tradeoffs.aspx?utm_source=feedburner&utm_medium=feed&utm_campaign=Feed%3A+AyendeRahien+%28Ayende+%40+Rahien%29&utm_content=Google+Reader)" and where can I read more about it? Googling did not find anything.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ayende has a typo.  Try EditorForModel() or EditorFor().

IMHO the best resource for all the EditorFor and DisplayFor resources is Brad Wilson's blog post:
http://bradwilson.typepad.com/blog/2009/10/aspnet-mvc-2-templates-part-1-introduction.html